# How do I increase the priority of a TCP packet in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, tcp

I have a server application that receives some special TCP packet from a client and needs to react to it as soon as possible by sending an high-level ACK to the client (the TCP ACK won't suite my needs).

However, this server is really network intensive and sometimes the packet will take too long to be sent (like 200ms in a local network, when a simple server application can send it in less than 1ms).

Is there a way to mark this packet with a high-priority tag or something like that in Delphi? Or maybe with the Win32 API?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Thanks for all the answers so far. I'll add some details. My product has the following setup: there are several devices that are built upon vehicles with WIFI conectivity. When they arrive at the garage, those device connect to my server and start to transmit data.

Because of hardware limitations, I implemented a high-level ACK to make the device aware that the last packet arrived successfully (please, don't argue about this - the data may be broken even if I got a correct TCP ACK). However, if I use my server software, that communicates with a remote database, to issue this ACK, I get very long delay (>200ms). If I use an exclusive software to do this task, I get small latencies (<1ms). So, I was imagining if I could just tell Windows to send those special packets first, as it **seems** to me that this package is getting delayed so the database ones can get delivered.

That's the motivation behind my question.

**EDIT 2**

As requested: this is legacy software and I'm using the legacy *dclsockets140.bpl* package and *Delphi 2010 (14.0.3593.25826)*.

Comment: What communications library are you using? Version of Delphi?

Comment: @Mef, it does. See my answer.

Comment: @user539484 urgent is not really the same as priorities

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  How far apart (route hops) are these two computers and how much network bandwidth do you have for your connection? Do you really think that a rush-shipment flag (TCP QOS) is going to have any effect?  I would challenge anybody to show any local area network or across-the-internet decrease in latency due to TCP QOS.  Haole. If you are experiencing 200 msec latency, I urge you to investigate your LAN and your PC loads and solve the problem by fixing the cause. QOS has NO EFFECT on a LAN or on a local computer.

Comment: This is something you have to take care of in the infrastructure. The best thing you can do is keep a separate TCP/IP connection just for these high prio messages. Perhaps you can use UPD/IP where the client sends them repeatedly; you won't need any acks but it is less reliable due to it's nature..

Comment: @Mef, OOB **prioritizes** some given segment(s) of the given stream over "regular" segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO it is very difficult to realize this. there are a lot of equipment and software involved. first of all, if you communicate between 2 different OS's you got a latency. second, soft and hard firewalls, antiviruses, everything is filtering/delaying your package.

you can try also to 'hack' the system(this involve some very good knowledge on how the frames/segments are packed/send,flow control,congestion,etc), either by altering it from code, either by using some tools like http://half-open.com/ or others.

Answer (score 1):

In short, passing `MSG_OOB` flag to the [`send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function marks the data as *"urgent"*. Detailed discussion about the OOB in the context of Windows Sockets implementation specifics is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: And the related advanced level reading is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: from my knowledge,in practice the Quality of Service is implemented directly on equipments(routers, etc)

Comment: And in practice, it's not turned on. Because nobody trusts the people who turn on the bits. I'd bet that internet routers ignore QOS bits, 99.99% of the time.

Comment: @WarrenP - I'm sure you're right.  If a good QOS could be negotiated, there would be a billing system for it and I would be getting flyers and spam for the service.  I don't get any spam for high-performance internet, (I mean guaranteed, measurable high-performance - not the 'high performance' every ISP says they have), so it cannot exist.

Comment: @MartinJames, heh. I think Warren P merely spotted a familiar words and didnt hesitate to share his renditions about "bits" and bets. What exactly do you agree with? Also, that was kinda medieval "philosophy" - if i dont see X then X definitely doesnt exist :-)

Comment: @user539484 - it's more like marketing philosophy - 'if nobody is trying to sell X then X definitely doesnt exist' :)